# Python pandas how to print first 10 max and min value from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get only the 10 items with highest value? and also the 10 items with lowest value?
i have tried .max() it only returns the value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICnw6.png)

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df=df = pd.read_csv('steam55.csv')
df.head()
df.shape
df.describe()
df.dtypes
X = df[['genres']]
X = pd.get_dummies(data=X, drop_first=True)
X.head()
Y = df['c.owners']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
coeff_parameter = pd.DataFrame(model.coef_,X.columns,columns=['Coefficient'])
coeff_parameter
```

data stored in coeff_parameter variable
I have tried

```
coeff_parameter.sort_values
```

but it doesn't work

```
coeff_parameter = pd.DataFrame(model.coef_,X.columns,columns=['Coefficient'].sort_values().head())
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Comment: `nlargest/nsmallest`

Comment: @QuangHoang where should i type nlargest/nsmallest?

Comment: Include your code and describe the structure in which you are storing the data.   For a list, sort (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html), then take the first 10 items like my_list[:10] and last 10 items like my_list[-10:].

Comment: `sort_values()` then `head()/tail()`.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh coeff_parameter.sort_values()head()?

Comment: `coeff_parameter.sort_values(['Coefficient']).head()`

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh is .head showing the smallest value?

Answer (score 1):

You should really make use of the search engine and look at the document of pandas. Google `pandas sort_values` or `pandas nlargest` will lead you to the right place.

Take a look at [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), `sort_values` works on DataFrame object, not list object. It sorts ascending by defalut with `ascending=True` in the method argument, which means lower value has smaller index.

`coeff_parameter = pd.DataFrame(model.coef_,X.columns,columns=['Coefficient'])` already returns the DataFrame object. All you need do is to do operations on this `coeff_parameter` dataframe object.

To get the max/min value of the `Coefficient` of `coeff_parameter`. You could either sort this column first then take first nth row from it or just use [pandas.DataFrame.nlargest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) or [pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html#pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest).

```py
coeff_parameter.nlargest(10)
coeff_parameter.nsmallest(10)

coeff_parameter.sort_values(['Coefficient']).head()
coeff_parameter.sort_values(['Coefficient']).tail()
```

Answer (score 0):

`coeff_parameter.nsmallest(n=10)`

and

`coeff_parameter.nlargest(n=10)`